# Paging With a Cartesian Product

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pagination, oracle9i

Please do add a comment if more information is needed to answer this question.

We have a query that returns a cartesian product.  Since there are a lot of results, there are potentially a ton of objects that get hydrated.  We'd like to do simple paging on the database end so it's fast, and so it only pulls n results starting at row n*page where n is say, 100.

The trouble we're running into is that a `distinct` is being done on the query so as to only return the necessary rows.  But, this ends up filtering the results so you get less than 100.

Because of this, even though we have the page number, we would have no idea where to start or stop without doing the query to first see the starting point (i.e. we can't use rownum), and potentially looping until we got 100 results, you get the idea.  It's messy.

If needed we can do straight up SQL, but something like refactoring the table isn't an option.

Either way I can't imagine we're the first ones to ever encounter the situation, so I'd like to know if there's a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** @nicolas78 posted a comment which exactly describes the situation.

Comment: I'm getting a vague idea of what you're doing. basically you don't know how to address the, say, 101th row of your result set because it's based on two parameters and lots of combinations get thrown away?

if so, I have no idea how to predict this (I assume the problem is not paging one forth or one back but jumping to something like page 5 where you have no clue how to get them, right?). which is not so helpful - just trying to clarify the conditions.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the problem. even if we ask for 100 results, all we could get back is 67. we have no idea what row to start at when  requesting page n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the DISTINCT further into the query, so that it has been done **before** pagination is applied.  For example:

```
select deptno from
  ( select deptno, rownum as rn from
      ( select DISTINCT deptno
        from   emp
        order by deptno
      )
    where rownum < :pagenum*100
  )
where rn > (:pagenum-1)*100;
```